# Range in .Select() not working on xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop, excel-2013, vba

I just want to select A1 to A3 to freeze pane. But xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes  freezes A1 to A10. I was experimenting for 3 hours is this line of code for 3 hours:

```
xlApp.Range("A1:A3").Select()
```

But still A1 to A10 are the cells that are freeze. I just want to freeze A1 to A3. Is this possible? Im using Visual Studio 2012 and Excel 2013

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'AccessdbtestDataSet.country' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.CountryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.AccessdbtestDataSet.country)
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM  country"
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=accessdbtest.accdb"
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim xlCenter As String = "center"

        xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


        //Merging cells
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:D1").MergeCells = True
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A2:D2").MergeCells = True
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A3:D3").MergeCells = True

        //Assigning text to the merge cells
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Republic of the Philippines"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 1) = "NCR"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(3, 1) = "Manila"

        //Put the text in the center of the merge cells
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:A1").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A2:A2").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A3:A3").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter

        For i = 5 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
                    DataGridView1(j, i - 3).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next

        //This line of code is not working <-------------------------<|
        xlApp.Range("A1:A3").Select()
        xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\excel\vbexcel.xlsx")
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

        MsgBox("You can find the file C:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xlApp.Range("A4").Select
```

Then apply the freeze panes.